# Inserting string into queue from within an Enum.each loop

Tags: enums, elixir

```
def process({:page_link, url}, queue) do
  IO.puts "Downloading page: #{url}"
  torrents = download(url) |> torrent_links
  Enum.each(torrents, fn(torrent) ->
    IO.puts "Adding torrent to queue: #{torrent}"
    queue = :queue.in({:torrent_link, torrent}, queue)
    IO.inspect queue
  end)
  queue
end
```

Maybe I'm doing things more complicated than they need to be. I have a list of strings ("torrents") that I want to set into the queue.

I've read that variables set within an Each loop aren't saved, so how can I accomplish this?

For every string `torrent` set it into the queue and return the new queue.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Enum.reduce/3`:

```
def process({:page_link, url}, queue) do
  IO.puts "Downloading page: #{url}"
  torrents = download(url) |> torrent_links
  Enum.reduce(torrents, queue, fn(torrent, queue) ->
    IO.puts "Adding torrent to queue: #{torrent}"
    IO.inspect :queue.in({:torrent_link, torrent}, queue)
  end)
end
```

Since `IO.inspect/1` returns the value after printing it, I've also merged the `queue =` and `IO.inspect` lines.

Answer (score 1):

First, you convert the torrent links into the things you want in the queue:

```
queue_elems = Enum.map(torrents, fn(t) -> {:torrent_link, torrent}
```

When you have that, you can feed that list to `Enum.reduce`, with the queue as an accumulator:

```
Enum.reduce(queue_elems, queue, fn(e, q) -> :queue.in(e, q))
```

This loops over the elements you want to insert, with the queue as the "accumulator" - the return value of the `:queue.in` is used on the next call as the new value for the accumulator, gradually shoving a list of elements into a single thing (hence "reducing"). Needless to say, both snippets can be combined in a pipe or even converted to a single step, but often I find it easier to keep the various processing steps apart until performance is a concern.

The reason your code doesn't work is that the variable in the loop is not the same as the variable outside the loop. Per http://elixir-lang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical/scoping.html#scope-nesting-and-shadowing:

> Any variable in a nested scope whose name coincides with a variable from the surrounding scope will shadow that outer variable. In other words, the variable inside the nested scope temporarily hides the variable from the surrounding scope, but does not affect it in any way.

So even though they have the same names, they are different things. It's something you need to wrap your head around when learning Elixir, but usually by using the more idiomatic approaches (like not manually looping with `Enum.each` but rather feeding your data to higher level functions like `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, etcetera) you can avoid code that's problematic in the respect completely.

(For this particular problem, there is a simpler solution: `:queue.from_list(queue_elems)` will make a new queue, and `:queue.join` can then be used to join the queue in the function argument with the queue that that generates).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3). [`:queue.from_list/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html#from_list-1) and [`:queue.join/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html#join-2) would do the trick:

```
def process({:page_link, url}, queue) do
  url
  |> download
  |> torrent_links
  |> Enum.map(& {:torrent_link, &1})
  |> :queue.from_list
  |> :queue.join(queue)
end
```